# recovery of usb flash drive: extracted image is full of zeros

Tags: usb, ddrescue

A usb flash drive (SanDisk cruzer micro 4 GB) of a friend of mine stopped working, no partition table is left (the only filesystem of partition should have been FAT32 or NTFS). And yes, there is no backup, I already asked this and said it wasn't a good idea to not have a backup.

With

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

I can see the basic data

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 3.8 GiB, 4025810432 bytes, 7862911 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9080e264
```

with no partition table.

So I tried

```
ddrescue --direct /dev/sdc imagefile logfile
```

and

```
ddrescue /dev/sdc imagefile logfile
```

and got zero read errors (first I was happy about it) and let foremost and photorec search this imagefile but they found nothing.

Then I had a closer look at the imagefile with mc also in hex view and only saw zeros. If I zip the 4GB imagefile, I get a 4MB file, so there is few different content that can be squeezed by the old zip compression.

I tried the USB3 and USB2 ports of my linux computer another friend of me tried the same with a windows computer.

What do you think? Why are there so much (if not only) zeros? Is the connection between the flash an the usb controller broken? Is there any chance to rescue the data?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't any chance to rescue data from the USB flash. I think the flash was zeroed. But you can try to find the lost partition by testdisk , look there [testdisk how to](https://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_with_testdisk)
If you can't restore partition then check the flash is good for writing as described at [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/376274/check-the-physical-health-of-a-usb-stick-in-linux).
If the flash is good then if was zeroed by humans arms.

Comment: Testdisk does not find any partion table. :(

Comment: Then check the flash is good or bad. You'll never restore the data form it.

Comment: I'd not use that drive again. The risk that it is somehow broken and will go south again with your data isn't worth the cost of a new drive anyway.